# Massive: Update object: Cannot update identity column

Tags: c#, dynamic, massive

I have following scenario...

- Massive Micro-ORM
- .NET framework 4.0
- SQL Server 2008R2

Model:

```
public class sUser : DynamicModel
{
    public sUser() : base(Model.strConnection, "Users", "UserId") { }
}

public class Test
    {
        public void UpdateUser(string user)
        {
            dynamic User = GetUser(user);

            //Dynamically generated User object has many columns
            // I Update following fields...
            User.Address1 = "123 Main Street";
            User.Address2 = "Suite# 456";
            User.CityName = "Princeton";
            User.State = "NJ";
            User.Zipcode = "08540";
            //And update some more fields in Users object

           //I could do this...
            //var upd = new { Address1 = "123 Main Street", Address2 = "Suite# 456", ...};
            //User.Update(upd, User.UserID);

            //But would like to pass entire object, so I do not have to form all updated name/value in the update statement
            User.Update(User, User.UserID);

            //But Users table has a column with IDENTITY SEED,
            //And if I pass entire object for update it errors out
            //Cannot update identity column 'RefNo'
        }

        public dynamic GetUser(string userName)
        { 
            dynamic table = new sUser();
            var objUser = table.First(UserName: userName);

            return objUser;
        }
    }
```

Users table has a column RefNo with `IDENTITY SEED=1`, and when I update entire User object, it errors out Cannot update identity column 'RefNo'. I would like to pass entire object for update rather than forming long update statement.

How can I handle this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Modify Massive.cs**
- Add following under **DynamicModel** class

```
private string IdentityColumn { get; set; }

 private string GetIdentityColumn()
 {
    return (string)Scalar("SELECT C.name AS IdentityColumn FROM sys.columns C Inner Join sys.tables T ON T.object_id = C.object_id WHERE C.is_identity = 1 And T.name = '" + TableName + "'");
 }
```

And under **CreateUpdateCommand** method add following...

```
IdentityColumn = GetIdentityColumn();
```

And under **foreach** loop modify **if statement** to following...

```
if (!item.Key.Equals(PrimaryKeyField, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && item.Value != null && item.Key != IdentityColumn)
```

Above change into Massive library would allow us to update model with identity column. Limitation: Works for Table with one IDENTITY column.

Answer (score 1):

If your Users table has a column `RefNo` with `IDENTITY SEED = 1`, then that would imply it is your primary key. In you `sUser` class, you are calling the base constructor with:

```
base(Model.strConnection, "Users", "UserId")
```

This call is telling Massive that the primary key column is `UserId` - what happens if you instead pass it `RefNo`?

**Edit:**

I think I see the problem you are having: Massive will generate an update statement including all the properties of your object, including `RefNo`. Because the database is taking care of this column (via `IDENTITY SEED`), you can't modify or set this value.

What I would suggest instead is taking advantage of the fact that `User` is returned as an `ExpandoObject`. What you could do is this:

```
((IDictionary<string, object>)User).Remove("RefNo");
User.Update(User, User.UserID);
```

What this will do is remove the `RefNo` property from the object, meaning that it won't be included in the update statement that gets created, which should in turn result in the `Update` call succedding.

Comment: UserId is PK of type UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, and also it acts as a foreign key in several other tables, hence RefNo can not acts as PK. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @nick_w, based on your answer I took little different approach. Please see my edit.